# LDAP Records Password Change Automatic in C#

Tags: ldap

I'm new in Ldap
now I tried changed ldap records' password with c#.
for example;
users in ldap
username:12345678900
password:78900
I can do bellow with help

```
try
    {
        searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(String.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", 
            domainController, container), 
            adminUser, adminPassword, authenticationTypes);

        searcher = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
        searcher.Filter = String.Format("sAMAccountName={0}", userName);
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.CacheResults = false;

        SearchResult searchResult = searcher.FindOne(); 

catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
```

how to do I?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the C# LDAP API but it looks similar to JNDI, where the `SearchResult` gives you either a `Context` or a DN from which you can get a `Context` via a lookup, and you can then change the attribute via the `Context`.

Comment: Firstly ,thank you for your interest,But How to do I?It is some complex code.I need change only records users' password